# How do I apply two svgs on one html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

So I have 2 graphs: a line graph and boxplot but I would like the boxplot next to the line graph but instead it is below. How do I make so that it is next to the line graph? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks!

I tried using 2 different SVGs but it did not work. Here is my code: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/mWGOEy0GHp1olZgNgtpA?preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.line {
    fill: none;                 
  stroke: url(#grad);    
  stroke-width: 2px; 
}
.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

</style>
<svg width="900" height="700">  
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 90, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 630, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

...more code 
</script>

//end of line graph 

//beginning of boxplot
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="svg2"></div>

<!-- To use the monochrome scale -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Tooltip style -->
<style>
.tooltip {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;  
}
</style>

<script>
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 70, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 80},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

...more code, end of boxplot
</script>
```

[This is what it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93NGe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code at plnkr, I can make them sit alongside each other simply by setting the width of the elements to small-enough values. It doesn't help that you're defining the width differently for the two elements (the line graph is using the `width` assigned to the HTML element, and the box plot's just setting its own width at 460). But if you set each to a specific, smaller value (like 200 initially), you'll see that they're displayed alongside each other fine.

```
<svg width="200" height="700">  
.
.
.
<!-- BOXPLOT -->
.
.
.
var margin = {top: 70, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 100},
    width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right,
```

Also, for some reason, you're rendering the two svg elements with completely different HTML (one is in an `svg` element and the other in a `span` with `id="svg2"`), which won't be helping. Make your HTML consistent and you'll have much more control over how it renders because the blocks will be treated the same way by default.

Comment: Ok so I got the graphs next to each other (see updated plunkr above) but the my x-axis on my line graph is in a weird spot. Also my tooltip for my boxplot is not underneath it. How would I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: To align the two graphs as you want next to each other, I'd just use normal CSS formatting. Similarly for the tooltip, you've already got a .tooltip class defined so I'd use that - you may need `position:absolute;` to let you position it as you want.

Comment: @pk1997 I see you've raised a separate question about interactions between the graphs based on this same example. If this answer has done the job for the initial problem, it'd be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of basic HTML elements - block and inline elements. Block elements (such as div's) will push elements that follow them down to the next row. Inline elements (such as span's) do not, instead sharing a row with the content that comes after it UNLESS there is not enough room for both of them.

If you want a block element to actually behave like an inline (in regards to line breaks), you can apply `float: left` to the CSS of that element.

Edit:
The way I would do this is add a class called `float-left` on the first SVG, and then modify one of your `<style>` tags to include

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
```

This will also allow you to add the `float-left` class to any other elements that you want to do this behavior to as well. I hope that helps.

Comment: I just modified my answer to hopefully explain a bit better

Comment: how do I add a class called float-left on the first SVG?

Comment: If you're SVG's are too big, they will automatically move the oversized SVG to another row. by default, it seems SVG is an inline element, so they should be on the same line by default. you can see it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LEQqBYrUGhb131XHb8aM?p=preview

Comment: Hmm still no avail. I have added my plunker code above if that helps you better. Do I need to delete something?